# Testing result of libsvm

Tags: machine-learning, libsvm

I am using libsvm for music classification. I have chosen binary classification.

In training phase, I successfully trained the two classes namely, classical and pop.

During testing phase, it is returning accuracy. I dont know what accuracy really means.

Whether it denotes the first class or second class in the set.

What does this accuracy means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the accuracy actually means is how accurately it could identify the label. For example, you have 240/256 as your accuracy. In this case, it could correctly identify 240 of them while 16 were wrongly identified. The predict_label returns the number of correct/incorrect labels. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i didn't catch the idea of a question, but i suppose the answer is - "percent of correctly classified feature vectors."